# Java 8 Stream - NullPointerException when working with Custom Collector

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have implemented a custom collector by implementing the Collector interface and overridding its methods. The Collector implementation is as follows:

```
class MyCustomCollector implements Collector<Person, StringJoiner, String>{

    @Override
    public Supplier<StringJoiner> supplier() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return () -> new StringJoiner("|");
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<StringJoiner, Person> accumulator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (joiner,person) -> joiner.add(person.name.toUpperCase());
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<StringJoiner> combiner() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (joiner1, joiner2) -> joiner1.merge(joiner2);
    }

    @Override
    public Function<StringJoiner, String> finisher() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return StringJoiner::toString;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics> characteristics() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is my Person class:

```
class Person implements Comparable<Object>{
    String name;
    int age;

    Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object obj){
        int returnValue;
        if(age ==((Person) obj).age)
            returnValue=0;
        else
            if(age >((Person) obj).age)
                returnValue = 1;
            else
                returnValue =-1;

        return returnValue;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if(!(obj instanceof Person))
            return false;

        return (age == ((Person) obj).age); 
    }

    public int hashCode()
    {  
        return name.hashCode();  
    } 

}
```

And Here is my calling statements...

```
List<Person> persons =
        Arrays.asList(
            new Person("Max", 18),
            new Person("Peter", 23),
            new Person("Pamela", 23),
            new Person("David", 12),
            new Person("Pam", 23));
String names2 = persons.stream()
            .collect(new MyCustomCollector());
```

When the above statement gets executed, i got a NullPointerException as follows:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3.getOpFlags(ReduceOps.java:185)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
>       at com.my.j8.TestStreams.main(TestStreams.java:231)

Can anybody tell where i am making the mistake?

Comment: Hint: start by looking for `null` in your program.

Comment: GhostCat I didn't do that at all.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here:

```
public Set<java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics> characteristics() {
    return null;
```

Return an **empty** set instead of null; like

```
private final static Set<Characteristics> EMPTY = Collections.emptySet();
```

...

```
return EMPTY;
```

or just

```
return Collections.emptySet();
```

(as the Collections class is already having some EMPTY constant on its own).

The core point is: this interface contains that method; and "I am not using this part" still requires you to "reasonably" implement that method. So keep that in mind for the future: *any* collection-returning interface allows for saying "no content" by returning an **empty** thing; instead of a **null** thing!

Of course, in the end the problem could be seen by the surrounding framework **not** checking if that method returns null. But as said: when you are dealing with collections of any kind, **forget** about using null. If there is nothing, create an **empty** collection object of that type!

One crucial step to avoid NPEs is by **not returning** null in the first place.

And beyond that: as Eugene is pointing out - you probably want to check really carefully of if you *really* should go with an empty Set here. In other words: did you look into [Characteristics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.Characteristics.html) and do understand the whole concept of them; and are you 100% sure that want "none" here?!

Comment: This resolved the issue. But even i am not using the Characteristics, then why do i need to return some empty set from Characteristics?

Comment: See my updated answer. And as that answer helped, please consider accepting.

Comment: @GhostCat you should really think this out carefully before NOT providing any characteristics. There are different optimizations being performed internally based on those, not providing any might break those.

Comment: @Eugene My main point was to help with his NPE; but you are correct; I enhanced my answer in that regard.

Comment: characteristics – allows you to specify the characteristics of the collector so that that it can be invoked safely and optimally. e.g. specifying Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH lets Java know that because you aren’t performing a final transformation, it doesn’t even need to invoke your finisher function.

Comment: @KaranVerma There isnt much point in quoting that javadoc to us. Thing is: it is your project, your code; you want to use that interface, so you, for yourself have to decide what you want to do here. And in case you really dont understand the meaning of these values; consider putting up another question.

Comment: It’s not needed to store the `Set` into a variable. `Collections.emptySet()` already returns the constant stored in `Collections.EMPTY_SET`…

Comment: @Karan Verma: you don’t need to specify the empty characteristics as you don’t need to implement the `Collector` interface at all. Just use the static factory method: `Collector.of( () -> new StringJoiner("|"), (joiner,person) -> joiner.add(person.name.toUpperCase()), (joiner1, joiner2) -> joiner1.merge(joiner2), StringJoiner::toString )`. But it’s worth noting that even that collector creation is an unnecessary re-invention of the wheel. You can simply use `Collectors.mapping( person -> person.name.toUpperCase(),
Collectors.joining("|"))` to achieve the same.